# WPF: DataGrid not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Problem:

I'm looking to create a `DataGrid` that updates automatically as new objects gets added into an `ObservableCollection`. As a prototype, I've made a `Timer` that adds new, unique objects into the `ObservableCollection`. The class in question inherits from a custom `ObservableObject` class that inherits from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Using breakpoints, I can see that the `ObservableCollection` updates, the `ObservableObject` class gets called and sets the right values, but the `DataGrid` never displays anything.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataColl, Mode=TwoWay}" >

</DataGrid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public ObservableCollection<DataClass> DataColl = new ObservableCollection<DataClass>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        Timer aTimer;
        aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

    }
    int index = 0;
            private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataColl.Add(new DataClass() { ID = index, time = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now),source="AIS"});
        index++;

    }


}
```

DataClass.cs

```
public class DataClass : ObservableObject
{
    private int _id;


    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _id, value);
        }
    }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set;}
}
```

ObservableObject.cs

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
 
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
            [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(storage, value)) return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            return true;
        }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is that `Threading.Timer`? if so you will need to use the [`Dispatcher.Invoke(Action or Lambda);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) to synchronise the Threads.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is pretty bad to do `this.DataContext = this;` Please use a `DependencyProperty`.

Anyway I guess you use the wrong `Timer`. Please go with `DispatcherTimer`

```
  private DispatcherTimer _Timer = new DispatcherTimer();

  private void StartDispatcherTimer()
        {
            _Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000 / FPS);
            _Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimerTick);
            _Timer.Start();
        }
```

I think u get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change your observable collection declaration as

```
private ObservableCollection<DataClass> dataColl; 
        public ObservableCollection<DataClass> DataColl
        {
            get { return dataColl; }
            set { dataColl = value; }
        }
```

initialize the collection inside the constructor and change your timer event as

```
     private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    DataColl.Add(new DataClass() { ID = index, time = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now), source = "AIS" });
                    index++;
                });   
           }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

Any chance you can explain why initializing the collection is important in this case?

Comment: @Lacynt The problem is that `DataColl` needs to be a property, with a `get` block, rather than a field, as you had it. Justin, may I suggest making the `DataColl` property readonly, because its setter doesn't raise `PropertyChanged` and it's not a dependency property?